# Update matrix to get distinct adjacent characters

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a matrix of characters from a to z lowercase English characters. Minimum characters to replace so adjacent characters are not the same. Adjacent for a character is right, left, top, and bottom.

**Example**

```
acaa
dddd
bbbb
ccce
```

**Output:**
`6`

**Explanation:**

```
We may replace some characters to get the final matrix as:
acac
dede
baba
cece

Number of replacements is 6.
```

This is my code that gives the correct minimum replacements.

```
public static int solve(char[][] matrix) {
    int m = matrix.length, n = matrix[0].length;
    int[][] next = {{0,1}, {0,-1}, {1,0}, {-1,0}};
    int result = 0;
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            char ch = matrix[i][j];
            String k1 = i+":"+j;
            if(set.contains(k1)) { // check if position is already updated
                continue;
            }
            for(int k=0; k<4; k++) {
                int x = i + next[k][0] , y = j + next[k][1];
                String key = x+":"+y;
                if(x >=0 && y>=0 && x<m && y <n && !set.contains(key)) {
                    if(matrix[x][y] == ch) {
                        result++;
                        set.add(key); // this position is updated
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am able to find the minimum replacements needed in the matrix. But now I want to update matrix. There can be many possibilities, but I want to print one of the possible correct matrix. How can we solve this.

Comment: [As before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76584913/), this is not a real attempt at all, and all you're learning is how to off-load your work. This behavior is not good for you, nor for your learning and nor for the site.

Comment: an all the places where you add the "key" to your `Set` you have the coordinates that you can replace with a different character. Just use a list of 5 different characters and pick the first one that is not in any of the surrounding positions. You know how to assign to an entry in a nested array?

Comment: Your code does not "find the minimum replacements needed in the matrix" correctly. Test case: `{"aa", "ab"}`.

Comment: "This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed". Well, that's one way to keep low-quality content open...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an algorithm and its implementation.

First, let's assign colors to the matrix like a chessboard: alternating black and white cells. Any pair of adjacent
cells has different colors.

Then, I will define a "chain" as a maximal subset of connected cells with the same value.
Find all the chains contained in the matrix.

For the matrix given in the question, they are:

- a
- c
- aa
- dddd
- bbbb
- ccc
- e

For every chain, count the number of black and white cells. Select the color with the least number of cells
(in case of a tie, the choice is arbitrary). Then change all the cells in the chain that have that color.

To sum it up:

- Partition the matrix into chains
- For every chain, select the minority color and change all the cells with that color

Java implementation:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Solver
{
    private Cell[][] matrix;
    private int N;
    private int M;
    private ArrayList<HashSet<Cell>> chains;

    public Solver(char[][] values)
    {
        N = values.length;
        M = values[0].length;
        matrix = new Cell[N][M];
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
            {
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.i = i;
                cell.j = j;
                cell.value = values[i][j];
                cell.color = (i+j) % 2==0 ? 'B' : 'W';
                matrix[i][j] = cell;
            }
        }
        chains = new ArrayList<HashSet<Cell>>();
    }

    public void solve()
    {
        System.out.println("Initial matrix:");
        print();
        findChains();
        int nb = 0;
        for(HashSet<Cell> chain : chains)
        {
            int nbB = getNumberOfCellsWithColor(chain, 'B');
            int nbW = chain.size() - nbB;
            changeValues(chain, nbB < nbW ? 'B' : 'W');
            nb += Math.min(nbB, nbW);
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + nb + " change(s) performed:");
        print();
    }

    private void findChains()
    {
        Cell cell = getUnassignedCell();
        while(cell!=null)
        {
            HashSet<Cell> chain = new HashSet<Cell>();
            chains.add(chain);
            addToChain(cell, chain);
            cell = getUnassignedCell();
        }
    }

    private Cell getUnassignedCell()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
            {
                if(matrix[i][j].chain==null)
                    return matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void addToChain(Cell cell, HashSet<Cell> chain)
    {
        chain.add(cell);
        cell.chain = chain;
        for(Cell neighbor : getNeighbors(cell))
        {
            if(neighbor.value==cell.value && neighbor.chain==null)
                addToChain(neighbor, chain);
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Cell> getNeighbors(Cell cell)
    {
        ArrayList<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
        addCell(cells, cell.i, cell.j-1);
        addCell(cells, cell.i-1, cell.j);
        addCell(cells, cell.i, cell.j+1);
        addCell(cells, cell.i+1, cell.j);
        return cells;
    }

    private void addCell(ArrayList<Cell> cells, int i, int j)
    {
        if(i>=0 && i<N && j>=0 && j<M)
            cells.add(matrix[i][j]);
    }

    private int getNumberOfCellsWithColor(HashSet<Cell> chain, char color)
    {
        int nb = 0;
        for(Cell cell : chain)
        {
            if(cell.color==color)
                nb++;
        }
        return nb;
    }

    private void changeValues(HashSet<Cell> chain, char color)
    {
        for(Cell cell : chain)
        {
            if(cell.color==color)
                cell.value = chooseValue(cell);
        }
    }

    private char chooseValue(Cell cell)
    {
        HashSet<Character> values = new HashSet<Character>();
        for(Cell neighbor : getNeighbors(cell))
            values.add(neighbor.value);
        if(!values.contains('a'))
            return 'a';
        if(!values.contains('b'))
            return 'b';
        if(!values.contains('c'))
            return 'c';
        if(!values.contains('d'))
            return 'd';
        return 'e';
    }

    private void print()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j].value);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static class Cell
    {
        public int i;
        public int j;
        public char value;
        public char color;
        public HashSet<Cell> chain;
    }
}
```

Test 1:

```java
public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char[][] values = {{'a', 'a'}, {'a', 'b'}};
        Solver solver = new Solver(values);
        solver.solve();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Initial matrix:
aa
ab

1 change(s) performed:
ba
ab
```

Test 2:

```java
public class Test2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char[][] values = {{'a', 'a', 'a'}, {'a', 'a', 'a'}, {'a', 'a', 'a'}};
        Solver solver = new Solver(values);
        solver.solve();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Initial matrix:
aaa
aaa
aaa

4 change(s) performed:
aba
bab
aba
```

Test 3:

```java
public class Test3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char[][] values = {{'a', 'c', 'a', 'a'}, {'d', 'd', 'd', 'd'}, {'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'}, {'c', 'c', 'c', 'e'}};
        Solver solver = new Solver(values);
        solver.solve();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Initial matrix:
acaa
dddd
bbbb
ccce

6 change(s) performed:
acab
cdcd
baba
cbce
```

### UPDATE

Unfortunately I have found a failing test case:

```java
public class Test4
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        char[][] values = {{'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'}, {'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'a', 'd'}};
        Solver solver = new Solver(values);
        solver.solve();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Initial matrix:
aaaaaa
cadcad

4 change(s) performed:
ababab
cadcbd
```

It can be done in only 3 changes:

```
abcaba
cadcad
```

I think that the chain partitioning is the correct first step, but then you need to process every chain in a more clever way than I did...